# How to show column data that contains keyword in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has one column called 'job_title', there are many job titles, I want to show all job title contains 'Professor'

I have the following code:

```
sunshin_df[sunshin_df['job_title'].isin(['Professor'])
```

But this only show title "Professor", other titles such as "Associate Professor" are not included

Then I tried to use .str.contains, but it doesn't work,

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

```
sunshin_df[sunshin_df['job_title'].isin(['Professor'].str.contains('Professor', na=False, case=False))]
```

What is the best and simplest way to show all value that contains the keyword I want?

Comment: try `sunshin_df[sunshin_df['job_title'].str.contains('Professor')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try following :

```
sunshin_df[sunshin_df['job_title'].str.contains('Professor')]
```

i.e check the value of the job_title column if it contains 'Professor' in it.

Comment: Can I understand that, in python, "isin" is for exact search while ".str.contains" is for search with keyword? But I should never use them together because they serve different functionality?

Comment: isin is used when your looking for an element in the list. I guess your use case is to check for a word/string within in a string. In this case contains is more useful.

Comment: I just tried it. It gives me "ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" There are NaN values in my dataframe, so then .str.contains won't work?

Comment: you can fill NA / NaN with empty string using fillna() method

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'job_title':  ['Professor', 'Accountant','Teacher','Associate 
Professor','Secretary','Professor']    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['job_title'])
df[df['job_title'].str.contains('Professor')]
```

Ouput:

```
    job_title
0   Professor
3   Associate Professor
5   Professor
```